# How to verify if WebElement is selected or not

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, getattribute

I want to verify if WebElement is selected or not.
This element exist (when is selected) in HTML as:

```html
<span id="user-settings-price-preview-checkbox" class="user-settings-selector-checkbox active"></span>
```

and when is not selected:

```html
<span id="user-settings-price-preview-checkbox" class="user-settings-selector-checkbox"></span>
```

How can I verify it using selenium and TestNG?

Comment: I know this has already been answered, but the Selenium Java API has a "isSelected"  method.

Comment: `_driver.findElement(By.xpath("XPath Locator")).isSelected( );`

http://seleniumtwo-by-arun.blogspot.com/2013/06/76-using-isselected-predefined-method.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To verify if the `WebElement` is selected or not you can try:

```
    String attr = driver.findElement(By.id("user-settings-price-preview-checkbox")).getAttribute("class");
    if(attr.contains("active"))
        System.out.println("WebElement selected");
    else
        System.out.println("WebElement NOT selected");
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for! Many Thx!

Comment: Not the way to do it since the state is applied by custom styling. You need to evaluate the computed style to validate that the element has the expected color, border... Checking the class is useless since you'll get a false positive if the CSS matching the class `active` were to be renamed, missing or simply ignored due to another CSS rule overriding the style.

Answer (score 0):

**Code snippet:**

```
String classAttribute = driver.findElement(By.id("user-settings-price-preview-checkbox")).getAttribute("class");

boolean isItemSelected = classAttribute.endsWith("active");

Assert.assertTrue(isItemSelected);
```